# Linq Get Distinct Values of Nested Elements

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to extract a list of distinct possible values (name, type) of a nested object.
How to get out the list of property names and their respective types from the following nested collection?

The data structure in C#:

```
Nodes (List<Node>)
    -  Node1: 
         -Properties (List<NodeProperty>) getter: Node1.Properties   
              -Property1:
                 -Name: "AAA"    (string) getter Property1.Name
                 -Type: "string" (string) getter Property1.Type
```

Example:

```
MyNodes:
    Node1: 
        Properties 
            Property1:
                Name: "AAA"   
                Type: "string"
            Property2:
                Name: "BBB"
                Type: "int"
    Node2: 
        Properties
            Property1:
                Name: "CCC"
                Type: "double"
            Property2:
                Name: "DDD"
                Type: "double"
```

Result

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> result;

//  content of result after the Linq magic:
//  AAA -> string 
//  BBB -> int
//  CCC -> double
//  DDD -> double
```

How can I extract this with Linq?
Extracting the distinct names worked out like this:

```
List<string> names = MyNodes.SelectMany(n => n.Properties.Select(np => np.Name)).Distinct().ToList();
// res: [AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD]
```

Is this a good start?

Is there a single Linq query solution to this?

**EDIT**

Minimal Test Classes and data:

```
public class Node{
    public List<NodeProperty> Properties;
}

public class NodeProperty
{
    public string Name;
    public string Type;
}    

var MyNodes = new List<Node>
{
    new Node {
        Properties  = new List<NodeProperty>
        {
            new NodeProperty {Name = "node1", Type="string"},
            new NodeProperty {Name = "node2", Type="int"},
        }
    },

    new Node {
        Properties  = new List<NodeProperty>
        {
            new NodeProperty {Name = "node3", Type="string"},
            new NodeProperty {Name = "node4", Type="int"},
        }
    },
    new Node {
        Properties  = new List<NodeProperty>
        {
            new NodeProperty {Name = "node1", Type="string"},
            new NodeProperty {Name = "node2", Type="int"},
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide your data as valid C# code? So that we can copy-paste-and-run.

Comment: Added some sample data and the classes.

Comment: That sample code looks familiar :) something wrong with the answer supplied?

Comment: Yes @AndrewP thanks for the sample code! :)
A list of same type (Node with same Property names and types) are duplicated in the list, I would have wanted it to be distinct. Can you adjust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without actually running it up and debugging... it's definitely possible, and I think it will look similar to:

`MyNodes.SelectMany(x => x.Nodes.SelectMany(y => y.Properties.Select(z =>new KeyValuePair<string, string>(z.Name, z.Type))).Distinct().ToList();`

**Edit:**

Ran this up in LinqPad. My resulting query was:
`nodes.SelectMany(n => n.Properties.Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(p.Name, p.Type))).Distinct().ToList();`

Based on the class & initialization below:

```
public class Node{
    public List<NodeProperty> Properties;
}

public class NodeProperty
{
    public string Name;
    public string Type;
}    
var nodes = new List<Node>
{
    new Node {
        Properties  = new List<NodeProperty>
        {
            new NodeProperty {Name = "node1", Type="string"},
            new NodeProperty {Name = "node2", Type="int"},
        }
    },
    new Node {
        Properties  = new List<NodeProperty>
        {
            new NodeProperty {Name = "node3", Type="string"},
            new NodeProperty {Name = "node4", Type="int"},
        }
    },

};
```

Comment: This looks good! However when 2 Nodes have the same properties, the same key values will be duplicated in the result. Can that be distinct?

Comment: Yep, you can add .Distinct() before or after the .ToList()

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!